# Václav Slavík's diff-pdf error message when running via batch file

Tags: batch-file

Have you guys used Václav Slavík's  [diff-pdf?](http://vslavik.github.io/diff-pdf/)

I'm currently using it to automate pdf files comparison.. Because it's free and it outputs  the result as a file. I needed to do it via batch file. This is my code so far:

```
@ECHO OFF
set /p i1=%1
set /p i2=%2
set /p i3=%3
c:\diff-pdf\diff-pdf --output-diff=i1 i2 i3
```

Running it from the batch file returns error message [image]

What went wrong? Is it my code in batch file? I search through google, it seems correct.

Comment: I suppose the only command needed in batch file is `@"C:\diff-pdf\diff-pdf.exe" "--output-diff=%~3" %1 %2` and the batch file must be called with name of first PDF file to compare as first parameter, name of second PDF file to compare as second parameter and name of output PDF file as third parameter. And if an application crashes it is caused by an error in source code of the application and not in a batch file used to start it. Most likely you started diff-pdf.exe with parameters not expected by this tool and therefore it crashed. Or one of the PDF files to compare resulted in the crash.

Comment: Oh my. THANKS!!!! I got it right now. Using the syntax given, I edited  my main batch file. And then I just called it from command prompt using this command line: 
sample.bat file1.pdf file2.pdf c:\outputFolder\output.pdf

Comment: Other than possibly the order of parameters (which is itself nominal anyway) the problem with your batch is simply that you are passing `i1` (for example) which is `i1`, not the *contents* of `i1` which is `%i1%`. In this case, `%n` can be substituted, but that's masking the real problem.

Comment: Based from your input, should I do in this way:
c:\diff-pdf\diff-pdf --output-diff=%i1% %i2% %i3%?
I tried it, but contents of my parameters are not being read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it right now. Using this syntax:

```
@"C:\diff-pdf\diff-pdf.exe" "--output-diff=%~3" %1 %2
```

I edited my main batch file. And then I just called it from command prompt using this command line:

```
sample.bat file1.pdf file2.pdf c:\outputFolder\output.pdf
```

Thanks to @Mofi